# How do I create a Crystal Report that lists members of Active Directory Groups

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have a task to automatically email a report of who is in a series of groups in AD.  I'd like to schedule a report to run once a month from Crystal Reports.

I have followed the instructions to create the OLE DB (ADO) connections and everything connects fine.

In my SQL query, I try:

```
SELECT member, descripton from 'LDAP://ou=blah,dc=blach,dc=blah' where  cn ='TheGroupName'
```

Crystal Reports allows this command to work.  (of course with real server parameters)  ;)

However, the member list is blank and the description list is blank.  If I add distinguishedName to the SELECT, it returns, so I know it's able to get the object attributes.

Also, I've noticed nested groups.  I would probably need to expand those out until I get the user list.

For example:

---

Group1

- Joe
- Jane
- Group2
- Group3

Group2

- Larry
- Michael

Group3

- Tuan
- Huyen

I saw a post that suggests doing a ldif to a file and then using CR to parse through it.  I'd like to keep this report simple as possible.

Is it even possible to do this?

Thanks,
TT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I got no one to respond... BUT I figured out how to do it.

What I did was I wrote a Powershell script (with AD 2008 modules) to create an XML file.

Then I use CR 2008 to feed from the XML and format it into a pretty report.

Here's my code. In my example, I have supergroups that nest other groups.  I need to separate the nested groups from the supergroups and then list out the users.

```
$theFile = new-object system.IO.StreamWriter("c:\temp\myfile.xml")

$theFile.WriteLine('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>')
$theSuperGroupArray = @("SuperGroup1","SuperGroup2)
$theFile.WriteLine('<ADContentGroups>')
foreach ($aSuperGroup in $theSuperGroupArray) {
$strMembers = get-adgroupmember $aSuperGroup

# main element
$theFile.WriteLine('<ADGroup>')
$theFile.WriteLine('<ADSuperGroup>' + $aSuperGroup + '</ADSuperGroup>')
if($strMembers){

foreach($objitem in $strMembers){
    if($objitem.objectClass -ne "user") {
        $theFile.WriteLine("<ADGroupElement>")

    $theFile.WriteLine("<GroupName>" + $objitem.name + "</GroupName>" )
    $strNestedMembers = get-adgroupmember $objitem.name 
    foreach ($objNestedMembers in $strNestedMembers) {
        $theFile.WriteLine("<Member>" + $objNestedMembers.name + "</Member>")
    }
    $theFile.WriteLine("</ADGroupElement>")


}}}
$theFile.WriteLine('</ADGroup>')

}
$theFile.WriteLine('</ADContentGroups>')
$theFile.Close()
```